# one-to-many bidirectional assoc.: difference in database and 2nd level cache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

Here are parts of two class types,

```
public class Address {
    Set<Employee>employees=new HashSet<Employee>();

public class Employee {
    private Address address;;
```

Employees works on the address, for example. The mapping to Hibernate of them is (partly),

```
<class name="Address">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <set name="employees" inverse="false">
         <cache usage="read-write"/>    
             <key column="address_" not-null="true"/>
             <one-to-many class="Employee"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Employee" >
    <cache  usage="read-write"/>
    <many-to-one name="address" column="address_" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

So we have a bidirectional one-to-many association. The persistence of the association is determined by the collection side , not by the Address references in the employees. To check this I  deliberately add Address references to both employees. When both employees are persisted to the database, I see this is indeed the case. But the two Address references  are  persisted to the second llevel cache, and this is what I do not understand.

```
Employee employee=new Employee(1l,"Foo1",1.00);
Employee employee2=new Employee(2l,"Foo2",2.00);
Address address=new Address(12l,"foostreet", "12 foo", "FooCity12");
Address address3=new Address(34l,"foostreet", "34 foo", "FooCity34");

address.getEmployees().add(employee);
address.getEmployees().add(employee2);

employee.setAddress(address3);                                 
employee2.setAddress(address3);                          

session.save(address);
session.save(address3);
session.save(employee);
session.save(employee2);

tx.commit();
```

Then in a new session,

```
employee= (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, 1l)l
address=employee.getAddress();
employee= (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, 2l);
address=employee.getAddress();
```

Without Ehcache address is (a proxy to) Address#12l, so the container of the set where the  employees belongs to, Address#12l. But with Ehcache address is aproxy to Address#34l, so the reference to the Address which we set deliberately.

I don't know how this could ever work, because

```
BackrefPropertyAccessor$BackrefSetter.set(Object, Object, SessionFactoryImplementor){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't maintain the bi-directionality of the relation, but instead rely on Hibernate (and the underlying relational model of the database) to "fix" it for you. As soon as you use a stateful OO representation the problem is exposed. You could most probably already observe it with the `Session` only.

Basically what happens is that you only update the "owning" side of the relationship, and not both. Given the underlying database is relational, and as such only holds the "FK" on one end, when you reload from that model, the problem disappears.

What you need to do is update both ends of the relationship, i.e. `employee.setAddress()` *AND* `address.addEmployee()` (instead of exposing the raw `Set<Employee>` to the user). Further more, if the employee was already associated to another address, it would need to be removed from that set too... This is where OO comes in very handy: as this logic should actually be part of the `.setAddress()` or `.addEmployee()` methods on the model, that would check if the there is anything to clean up, and call back into the other end, encapsulating that logic neatly away from the consumer of the `Address` or `Employee` class.

Comment: When I do not use the 2nd level cache, it works. The problem is when there is a 2nd level cache.

Comment: Right, the Cache actually uses a more "OO" model than your RDBMs

Comment: But your OO code is the issue, and you could perceive the problem only with using your model that way. See https://gist.github.com/alexsnaps/f46a87de25c8e41848a5